# Oracle data distribution across date index

Tags: oracle, indexing

There's a situation that arises in large database tables (~50 million rows) where users need to browse date-indexed records.

But users browsing the data do not necessarily know where on the timeline data occurs and where the gaps are.  In past projects, I've quantized the records into 24-hour "buckets", and used that to create a bar-graph timeline, where the height of the bar indicates the number of records in that period.  This allowed users to focus in on areas where data actually exists.

The drawback of this solution is that the record counts must be continually updated and maintained (if data can be inserted/removed from any point on the timeline).

Is there a more elegant solution to getting these aggregate record counts?  For instance, by peeking at a date index and seeing how many values there are associated with that index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will actually work for you, but it sounds like what you're looking for are [histograms](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/stats.htm#i41591). If a histogram exists for your index, you can query `USER_HISTOGRAMS` to get a rough idea of the distribution of values across the index.  The downside of this is that it will only be accurate as of the last time statistics were gathered for your index, so if your data changes often, it may not be up-to-date.

Comment: This sounds promising.  I'll check back on Monday and see if any more answers have come in.  If nothing else is a more perfect fit, I'll choose this one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No too sure what you are asking but faced with a similar situation i would do the following:

Partition the table on s_date. (is that what your "bucket" is, a partition?)

Create a bitmap index on s_date.

Generate statistics like this:

```
select s_date,  count(s_date) from big_table where s_date > '01-APR-11' group by s_date;
```

Also you may want to read up on oracle's "Gathering Optimizer Statistics", it's nice to know.

cheers.

Comment: Sort of.  The buckets were created in code which was accessing the data, not in Oracle itself.  I don't want to partition the table on 24-hour periods because we have several years worth of data.  I guess I'm really wondering if there's a way to look into the date index and count the values attached to various leaves of the index tree.

Comment: @Klay: If you partitioned by day and you used a local index you could get good estimates very quickly from USER_IND_PARTITIONS.NUM_ROWS.  Why don't you want to partition the data by day?  Creating hundreds of partitions isn't necessarily a problem, especially with the most recent version of Oracle.  INTERVAL partitioning will automatically create the partitions you need, and deferred segment creation and automatic segment space management can help reduce the amount of storage overhead with partitioning.